# Transport timeout too short causes Angular Socket.IO web socket to close before connection established

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io

I keep getting the warning
Websocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12345/sockjs-node/123/124gi9a/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established
 in the console every time I run my Angular app using VS.

Looking at the call stack; it seems to be because of transport time out after several failed attempts to connect. Then it closes the transport.

EDIT: I found that increasing the transport timeout by using the second line of code [here](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/pull/413/commits/aa1fd5882e6c8ba59c55161dd855831953b88450) fixed the warning. However I don't know why this pull request was not approved. I still don't know what's a good long term solution to lengthening to timeout.

Comment: Can you show how you implemented this fix please? That pull request seems to be for v1.1.5 of sockjs-client. I'm running v 1.4.0 and still having the same problem.

Comment: Please see my new answer, below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give details on what I did:

There's a line in node_modules\sockjs-client\dist\sockjs.js

```
var timeoutMs = (this._rto * Transport.roundTrips) || 5000;
```

I just commented it out.

Below it should be a line like this:

```
// calculate timeout based on RTO and round trips. Default to 5s. Min timeout is null, can be overridden
var timeoutMs = (
    (this._rto > this._transportMinTimeout ? this._rto : this._transportMinTimeout) * Transport.roundTrips
) || 5000;
```

Comment: And everytime the sock-client component gets updated to a new version...?